# How frequenty have space walkers been changed based on space suit configuration?

Tags: iss, astronauts, eva

On Friday, March 29, two astronauts were supposed to conduct what would have become the first all female space walk, Christina Koch and Anne McClain. After her first space walk on March 22, Anne McClain decided that a medium space suit was more appropriate for her, and she requested that the assignment be changed. If the EVA suit had been configured in advance, it could have happened, but there wasn't time to make the swap.

https://twitter.com/AstroAnnimal/status/1110896720408383489

How often does this kind of thing happen? Due to the potential historic nature of such a spacewalk, this one is much more well known than most, but I'm curious if this is a common occurrence to swap out astronauts for space walks based on the configuration of EVA suits.

Comment: Ack! Those twitter comments... Why do I ever read them. Also-- I doubt very often. It would only happen if an astronaut felt uncomfortable during an EVA and needed a  new size right? Going to guess she won't swap back down next time. So I'd assume it only happens after first-time EVA's.

Comment: I guess it could happen when doing some kind of a fit check as well prior to initiating an EVA? No idea really, but... And yeah, the comments are pretty toxic, but inspired me to ask this question.

Comment: Would you treat [this quote](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2019/03/nasa-spacesuit-women-spacewalk/585805/) as an answer or a frame challenge? "Today astronauts still use the same 40-year-old space suits; NASA hasn’t made any new ones since they were designed...The space station currently has six people on board. Their space-suit wardrobe contains six space-suit torsos, two each in medium, large, and extra large. But only some are ready for space walks; one medium and one extra large are spares, and require hours of work to prep for use..."

Comment: Not an answer. At best it provides a bit of context.